# Shared preferences - select ringtone basic implementation

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm almost at a stage where my app is getting to a good state. So far for everything I have used just defaults but now I want the user to be able to select a ringtone to use for notifying them.

My code for defaults is:

```
        note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
```

Does anyone know where a good tutorial is, or have some code they could share for changing this to user selectable ringtones? I've had a look at the documentation but found it a little confusing thus far. Any help is much appreciated as always.

Edit: I think the XML part of this looks ok, it's just the Java/Android side of it I'm having trouble with - thanks!

Comment: Hmm, my accepted answer doesn't seem to work after trying it - see explanation below - any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you add a [RingtonePreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/RingtonePreference.html) to your Preferences screen. This lets the user select a ringtone which will be saved to your [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). In the part of your code where you say

```
note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
```

instead do

```
note.sound = Uri.parse(context.getSharedPreferences("my_preferences_file_name", 0).getString("the_name_of_your_ringtone_preference", ""));
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like exactly what I want :). I'll accept the answer when it allows me to.

Comment: So I've tried it and I'm getting an error: I added 
 private Context context; to the class and imported android.content.* but now I get the error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Uri

Comment: See my edit. I forgot to convert the string (from SharedPreferences) to a Uri.